# PDF Signature - Embed separatly signed hash

Tags: c#, pdf, hash, digital-signature

I am trying to sign a PDF Document using two web services in two servers. But it is showing "Document has been altered or corrupt since it was signed" in Adobe Reader. Can anybody suggest what is wrong in following code.

PROCEDURE
1. Web service (WS) on Server A, Generate hash from PDF and sent to WS on Server B for signing.
2. WS on Server B signs hash.
3. WS on Server A receives signed hash and Embed in PDF document.

CODE

GENERATE HASH

```
 private PDFHashData generateHash(byte[] content, string userName)
    {
        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(content);
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();

        PdfStamper stamper = PdfStamper.CreateSignature(reader, ms, '\0');
        PdfSignatureAppearance appearance = stamper.SignatureAppearance;
        appearance.SetVisibleSignature(new Rectangle(500, 150, 400, 200), 1, signatureFieldName);
        appearance.SignDate = DateTime.Now;
        appearance.Reason = Reason;
        appearance.Location = Location;
        appearance.Contact = Contact;
        StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();
        buf.Append("Digitally signed by");
        buf.Append("\n");
        buf.Append(userName);
        buf.Append("\n");
        buf.Append("Date: " + appearance.SignDate);
        appearance.Layer2Text = buf.ToString();
        appearance.Acro6Layers = true;
        appearance.CertificationLevel = 0;
        IExternalSignatureContainer external = new ExternalBlankSignatureContainer(PdfName.ADOBE_PPKLITE, PdfName.ADBE_PKCS7_DETACHED);
        MakeSignature.SignExternalContainer(appearance, external, 8192);

        byte[] hash = SHA256Managed.Create().ComputeHash(appearance.GetRangeStream());

        StringBuilder hex = new StringBuilder(hash.Length * 2);
        foreach (byte b in hash)
            hex.AppendFormat("{0:x2}", b);

        PDFHashData phData= new PDFHashData();
        phData.Hash = hex.ToString();
        phData.Content = Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray());
        return phData;
    }
```

SIGN HASH

```
    byte[] StringToByteArray(string hex)
    {
        return Enumerable.Range(0, hex.Length)
                         .Where(x => x % 2 == 0)
                         .Select(x => Convert.ToByte(hex.Substring(x, 2), 16))
                         .ToArray();
    }
    private Stream getCertificate()
    {
// Base 64 byte - PFX file with private key
        return new MemoryStream(Convert.FromBase64String("..................................AgIEAA=="));
    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Stream stream = Request.InputStream;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[stream.Length];
        stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        byte[] hash = StringToByteArray(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer));

        Pkcs12Store store = new Pkcs12Store(getCertificate(), "*******".ToCharArray());
        String alias = "";
        foreach (string al in store.Aliases)
            if (store.IsKeyEntry(al) && store.GetKey(al).Key.IsPrivate)
            {
                alias = al;
                break;
            }
        AsymmetricKeyEntry pk = store.GetKey(alias);
        X509CertificateEntry[] chain = store.GetCertificateChain(alias);
        List<Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509Certificate> c = new List<Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509Certificate>();
        foreach (X509CertificateEntry en in chain)
        {
            c.Add(en.Certificate);
        }
        PrivateKeySignature signature = new PrivateKeySignature(pk.Key, "SHA1");
        String hashAlgorithm = signature.GetHashAlgorithm();
        PdfPKCS7 sgn = new PdfPKCS7(null, c, hashAlgorithm, false);
        DateTime signingTime = DateTime.Now;
        byte[] sh = sgn.getAuthenticatedAttributeBytes(hash, null, null, CryptoStandard.CMS);
        byte[] extSignature = signature.Sign(sh);
        sgn.SetExternalDigest(extSignature, null, signature.GetEncryptionAlgorithm());

        Response.Write(Convert.ToBase64String(sgn.GetEncodedPKCS7(hash, null, null, null, CryptoStandard.CMS)));
    }
```

EMBED SIGNATURE TO PDF

```
private byte[] signPDF(byte[] content, string userName, byte[] pk)
    {
        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(content);
        MemoryStream os = new MemoryStream();
        IExternalSignatureContainer external = new MyExternalSignatureContainer(pk);
        MakeSignature.SignDeferred(reader, signatureFieldName, os, external);
        return os.ToArray();
    }
```

Comment: You're doings hex + base64 encoding in the first step (why ever) while I cannot find any base64 decodeing in the snd step?

Comment: Hex encoding is done only on hash. Base64 encoding is done on PDF content and certificate content. Base 64 decoding of files are not included above because the problem is in hash signing part.

Comment: In `generateHash` you calculate a hash using `SHA256Managed` but in `Page_Load` you instantiate `PdfPKCS7` with the hash algorithm retrieved from a `PrivateKeySignature` initialized with `"SHA1"`. Are you sure that matches?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For those who are interested I am posting the answer.
I ended up using itextsharp 5.5.10. Code is given below,

**Initialize PDF object**

```
public PDFSigning(byte[] Content, string UserName)
    {
        content = Content;
        reader = new PdfReader(content);
        ms = new MemoryStream();
        stamper = PdfStamper.CreateSignature(reader, ms, '\0');
        appearance = stamper.SignatureAppearance;
        userName = UserName;
    }

private Stream getCertificate()
    {
        return new MemoryStream(Convert.FromBase64String("************************=="));
    }
```

**Generate hash**

```
 private string generateHash()
    {
        appearance.SetVisibleSignature(new Rectangle(500, 150, 400, 200), 1, signatureFieldName);
        appearance.SignDate = DateTime.Now;
        appearance.Reason = Reason;
        appearance.Location = Location;
        appearance.Contact = Contact;
        StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();
        buf.Append("Digitally signed by");
        buf.Append("\n");
        buf.Append(userName);
        buf.Append("\n");
        buf.Append("Date: " + appearance.SignDate);
        appearance.Layer2Text = buf.ToString();
        appearance.Acro6Layers = true;
        appearance.CertificationLevel = 0;
        PdfSignature dic = new PdfSignature(PdfName.ADOBE_PPKLITE, PdfName.ADBE_PKCS7_DETACHED)
        {
            Date = new PdfDate(appearance.SignDate),
            Name = userName
        };
        dic.Reason = appearance.Reason;
        dic.Location = appearance.Location;
        dic.Contact = appearance.Contact;

        appearance.CryptoDictionary = dic;
        Dictionary<PdfName, int> exclusionSizes = new Dictionary<PdfName, int>();
        exclusionSizes.Add(PdfName.CONTENTS, (csize * 2) + 2);
        appearance.PreClose(exclusionSizes);


        HashAlgorithm sha = new SHA256CryptoServiceProvider();
        Stream s = appearance.GetRangeStream();
        int read = 0;
        byte[] buff = new byte[0x2000];
        while ((read = s.Read(buff, 0, 0x2000)) > 0)
        {
            sha.TransformBlock(buff, 0, read, buff, 0);
        }
        sha.TransformFinalBlock(buff, 0, 0);

        StringBuilder hex = new StringBuilder(sha.Hash.Length * 2);
        foreach (byte b in sha.Hash)
            hex.AppendFormat("{0:x2}", b);

        return hex.ToString();
    }
```

**Sign hash**

```
 public byte[] SignMsg(string hexhash)
    {
        byte[] hash = hexToByteArray(hexhash);
        Pkcs12Store store = new Pkcs12Store(getCertificate(), "*********".ToCharArray());
        String alias = "";
        foreach (string al in store.Aliases)
            if (store.IsKeyEntry(al) && store.GetKey(al).Key.IsPrivate)
            {
                alias = al;
                break;
            }
        AsymmetricKeyEntry pk = store.GetKey(alias);
        X509CertificateEntry[] chain = store.GetCertificateChain(alias);
        List<Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509Certificate> c = new List<Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509Certificate>();
        foreach (X509CertificateEntry en in chain)
        {
            c.Add(en.Certificate);
        }
        PrivateKeySignature signature = new PrivateKeySignature(pk.Key, "SHA256");
        String hashAlgorithm = signature.GetHashAlgorithm();
        PdfPKCS7 sgn = new PdfPKCS7(null, c, hashAlgorithm, false);
        DateTime signingTime = DateTime.Now;
        byte[] sh = sgn.getAuthenticatedAttributeBytes(hash, null, null, CryptoStandard.CMS);
        byte[] extSignature = signature.Sign(sh);
        sgn.SetExternalDigest(extSignature, null, signature.GetEncryptionAlgorithm());
        return sgn.GetEncodedPKCS7(hash, null, null, null, CryptoStandard.CMS);

    }
```

**Sign PDF**

```
private byte[] signPDF(byte[] pk)
    {

        byte[] paddedSig = new byte[csize];
        System.Array.Copy(pk, 0, paddedSig, 0, pk.Length);

        PdfDictionary dic2 = new PdfDictionary();
        dic2.Put(PdfName.CONTENTS, new PdfString(paddedSig).SetHexWriting(true));
        appearance.Close(dic2);

        //System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/temp.pdf"), ms.ToArray());
        return ms.ToArray();

    }
```

Comment: Thank for taking time to share the code. Can you please share the complete code for better understanding?

Comment: @ShashiJeevanM.P. I used this answer to create my code and it is available [here](https://github.com/mqueirozcorreia/SignFileByHash/blob/master/Server/Services/PDFSigner.cs):

Comment: @mqueirozcorreia I got the code from some other place. Thank you anyway for sharing.

Comment: @Matt can you share the full code for this? I'm facing the same problem

Comment: What is `csize`?